# Как рекламные сервисы, например Яндекс Директ, узнают что нам нужно?

Tags: веб-программирование, поисковые-системы, реклама

Достаточно популярный вопрос на разных "вопросах мэйл ру" и прочих. Но интересно как же это на самом деле может быть устроено. Понятно, что "читают куки, в которых хранятся поисковые запросы" - огромное заблуждение, ибо не безопасно читать куки других сайтов. Я так понимаю информация о том, что я посещал и что искал, сохраняется на серверах того же гугла, например.

Но вот как он меня идентифицирует и выдает рекламу? По идее можно хранить индивидуальный идентификатор поисковой истории в куки, скажем для google.com. Но тогда я же не смогу отправить его с другого сайта (example.com на котором нужно вывести рекламу), потому что опять таки не безопасно. По IP адресу тоже бред, ибо он может быть динамическим, да и увидели бы рекламу все компьютеры в сети, а не только я.

Или может это всё браузер делает? Сайт не имеет доступа к этой всей ерунде, а браузер имеет. И получается с другого браузера уже не будет такой рекламы?

В общем вот такие у меня рассуждения, ответа не нашел ни в интернете, ни в своих "мысленных экспериментах".

**UPD**. Для тех кто не понял. Суть вопроса не в том, как информация собирается. В этом ничего сложного нет. Суть в следующем.

Информация собрана на одном сайте, ну пусть service.com. Но мы заходим с другого сайта drugoi.ru. И вот на этом сайте установлен сервис от service.com, который получает некоторую информацию с сайта service.com (на примере, что я привел, яндекс директ - это данные, где лазил и чего искал пользователь, или же сразу готовую рекламу). Но чтобы это сделать, ему (сервису от service.com, который установлен на сайте drugoi.ru) нужно отправить нечто, чтобы сайт service.com понял "Ага, так это ж тот самый чувак, что искал вчера стиральную машину, держи-ка рекламу стиралок". И я не могу понять что именно и как передается. Учитывая что в этом случае возможности на кроссдоменные запросы сервиса ограничены, так как он встроен в другой сайт.

Тут в комментариях написали, что можно сохранять в куки, и сделать рекламу в фрейме. Но о эти сервисы не используют фреймы, насколько я знаю.

Comment: А зачем Вам читать файлы кук с другого сайта. Как по вашему работают различные API или фреймы в браузере? Идет запрос к Яндексу, который отправляет обратно нужный токен и по которому в дальнейшем с Вами и работают или сразу информацию. К примеру, типичный виджет соц.сетей как-то же передает информацию о том, что Вы - это Вы. Есть решение еще проще, просто вставить фрейм. В данном случае вопрос с безопасностью решен, Вы не сможете получить больше, чем позволяет система.

Comment: Та я понимаю, что не нужно ничего читать с куки. Просто это очень частое заблуждение (вот например мой препод в универе уверен, что рекламные сайты таки читают куки, между прочим), поэтому я и сказал слово за этот способ. Но вот просто я не понимаю как эти виджеты работают, в этом то и вопрос состоял. Да, про фрейм я тоже думал - самый простой вариант, но разве вся эта реклама - фрейм? Вроде нет.

Comment: И да, это мне как раз и интересно. Вот он передает этот токен. Но откуда он его берет? Откуда виджеты с тех же соцсетей понимают что я это я? Для самого сайта, всё просто - это куки, где хранится токен. Но для этого API? Кроссдоменные запросы же не позволяют послать куки. Или может эти API как то завернуты по особенному? Надеюсь теперь понятно, что я конкретно хочу узнать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайт собирает информацию о поисковых запросах клиента и сохраняет у себя в базе или еще где-то, к примеру, в тех же куках. В общем-то, это не важно. Далее Вам надо со стороннего сайта получить эту информацию. Для этого может использоваться технология кроссдоменных запросов.

Пример через iframe запрос.

***Сайт, который получает информацию.***

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="token"></div>
        <script>
            //Ловим тут информацию со стороннего сайта
            window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
                document.getElementById("token").innerText = e.data;
            },
            false);
        </script>
        <iframe hidden id="fr" src="http://token.my/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Сайт сборщик, с которого получаем , в данном случае из куков:***

```
<?php
    //Сборщик информации
    if(isset($_GET["secret_pass"]))
    {
        setcookie("secret_pass", $_GET["secret_pass"], time()+1000); 
        echo $_GET["secret_pass"];
        return;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //проверяем пользователя и высылаем ему информацию, к примеру рекламу или secret_pass к API
            parent.postMessage("<?php echo $_COOKIE["secret_pass"]; ?>", "*");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

В данном случае отправляется запрос через `iframe`, но получить напрямую к нему доступ нельзя из-за политики безопасности `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Только сайт отправитель предоставляет Вам возможность получить эту информацию, пробрасывая вверх `postMessage`. После того, как это сделано, теперь эту информацию можно перехватить через `EventListener("message", ..., false);` и использовать. Либо сразу встроить, либо использовать как token к стороннему API. Таким образом мы получаем нужный ключ, рекламу и т.д. со стороннего сайта.

Если хотите знать больше, прочитайте про CORS, PostMessage и возможно заинтересует OAuth.

Comment: Да, это то что я хотел узнать ) Спасибо ) Поизучаю по подробнее эту тему )

Answer (score 1):

На большинстве сайтов стоят я.метрики и прочие г.аналитики. Они передают инфу о юзере. Далее она собирается и анализируется гораздо обширней, чем это видится снаружи. + всякие соцсети и пр, где вообще добровольно юзеры сливают такое о себе..

Не говоря уже за поиск в ПС.